# Show $\sqrt{5}$ is the best possible constant in Hurwitz Theorem (Number Theory).

Tags: number-theory

According to Hurwitz Theorem (Number Theory), for every irrational number $x$ there are infinitely many relatively prime integers $m$ and $n$ such that $$\left|x - \frac{m}{n}\right| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}n^2}.$$

> I want to show that no constant larger than $\sqrt{5}$ is the best possible, in the sense that there exists an irrational for which the inequality would not have infinitely many solutions if $\sqrt{5}$ were replaced by a larger constant.

Following [Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(number_theory)) if we replace $\sqrt{5}$ by any number $A > \sqrt{5}$ and let $x = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ then there exist only finitely many relatively prime integers $m$ and $n$ such that the formula above holds. Why do there only exist finitely many in this assertion? Also, what other counterexamples come to mind?

Comment: What kind of a 'why' are you looking for?  Essentially, we can bound how close approximations to $\phi=\frac12(1+\sqrt{5})$ come to it, and the Hurwitz theorem is that bound. What's more, _every_ counterexample 'looks like' $\phi$; if we remove all irrationals "related to" $\phi$ from the picture, then the bound rises to $2\sqrt{2}$ from $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, could you give a reference to the bound rising claim?

Comment: @lhf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_number is one pointer; Wikipedia's explanations here are pretty sketchy even by Wikipedia standards, but it at least gives a few directions to look in.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I was overthinking and misread the statement Wikipedia had mentioned; your explanation made it click for me. Although, those counterexamples and reference to Lagrange numbers are quite fascinating. Thank you for mentioning them.

Comment: @Cauchy The answer to your question is the proof of Theorem 194 in Hardy and Wright's Intro to Theory of Numbers.  The proof is just a few lines and requires no background at all.  I can provide if you wish.